# Line break while retrieving data from database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a form that contains a textarea. And the contents stored in a database. And there is a page (using `php echo`) to display the content. If somebody typed the content without space, the layout is going wrong.

For example:

> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

I need anything that automatically inserts a line break.

Answer (score 2):

Look at built in function [**wordwrap**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

> Wraps a string to a given number of
>   characters using a string break
>   character.

Comment: This requires knowing in PHP what your character limit will be. Even if your layout is fixed, this isn't particularly modular. Handling it on the clientside is better.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to set `overflow: scroll` in css for that div.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `word-wrap: break-word;` CSS property when displaying it, but it is a CSS3 property i.e. it works on Google Chrome, FireFox4 , Opera 10, IE9 ONLY.